# How can I iterate over files in a folder to move each file with specific extension

Tags: python, file, scripting

I copied a script for downloading YouTube videos and am currently in a process of tweaking it. The problem is, I can't find a way to move music that I downloaded to a desired folder.

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\vucin\Desktop\YouTube Download')

#Downloading songs

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(download_options) as dl:
    with open('songs.txt', 'r') as f:
        for song_url in f:
            dl.download([song_url])

#Moving files

for file in os.walk():
    if '.mp3' in file:
        shutil.move('C:\\Users\\vucin\\Desktop\\YouTube Download\\file',
                    r'C:\Users\vucin\Desktop\Muzika')

input()
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? And have you tried `os.listdir()`?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It looks like I screwed up, because I am a beginner and I thought that the error it was spiting was because I screwed up the code for moving the file but it looks like it is youtube.dl that's running into a problem. Here is a picture: https://imgur.com/gallery/tZYjlYe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Python 3.4 on, you can use `pathlib` like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

for file in Path("C:\Users\vucin\Desktop\YouTube Download").glob("*.mp3"):
    new_path = str(file.resolve()).replace("YouTube Download", "Muzika")
    shutil.move(file, new_path)
```

With `Path` in combination with `glob`, you can search for all files with a specific pattern (e.g., the extension) using the `*` wildcard. As your new destination path deviates from the source path just a little bit, you could use `replace` to specify the new path. To learn more about `pathlib` see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: It looks like I screwed up, because I am a beginner and I thought that the error it was spiting was because I screwed up the code for moving the file but it looks like it is youtube.dl that's running into a problem. Here is a picture: imgur.com/gallery/tZYjlYe

Comment: I don't see how the error in the image you show is related to your question. Looks like you are feeding a string containing a new line character (`\n`) to your downloader. However, as this is a completely different question, you might want to consider to open a new one. Also, try to be as specific as you can about your problem and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code [within your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) - and include your traceback in your question

Comment: Never mind, .txt file contained empty lines so I added an exception in for loop because it got bugged while iterating trough empty lines of code and now it looks like everything is okay, Your code is actually the solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

all_files = os.listdir(path_to_your_files)
for file_ in all_files:
    if '.mp3' in file_:
        try:
           os.rename(old_path, new_path)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(e)
```

Comment: where path_to_your_files= 'C:\\Users\\vucin\\Desktop\\YouTube Download', old_path = path_to_your_files+'\\'+file_

Comment: It looks like I screwed up, because I am a beginner and I thought that the error it was spiting was because I screwed up the code for moving the file but it looks like it is youtube.dl that's running into a problem. Here is a picture: imgur.com/gallery/tZYjlYe

Comment: the script above assumes that you've already downloaded mp3 files and you just want to move them into a separate directory.